# Problems with callbacks using emscripten with pthreads

Tags: c++, audio, webassembly, emscripten

`emscripten_set_click_callback` does not work with multithreading.

I'm not sure why, but certain functions like `emscripten_set_click_callback` and other similar input functions don't work with pthreads enabled, it gives an error saying it cannot target thread for callback. I need to enable input to have audio in the browser work and there's nothing I can find in the docs about this issue or how to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"don't work"*? which is the return value of `EMSCRIPTEN_RESULT`?

Comment: Are those functions limited to be called is main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I'm not crazy, and it indeed was a bug. The solution was to run emsdk install tot and it now works. Must have been a newer update, which is strange considering I had just updated emscripten about a week ago.